# Android : "Paste" text in application from overlay app

Tags: android

I am trying to build myself a custom application (something similar to Edge Panels on android) that would allow me to automate some of my routine tasks in writing.

What I build is an application that show an overlay toolbar on the side of the screen and that would allow me to access some macros producing text that would then be copied in a text field in the main application that is launched behind the overlay.
For example when I use a note app, I can push a button from that overlay toolbar to insert a piece of text generated by the overlay toolbar in my note app at the cursor position.

I had a look to ClipboardManager. I get how to "copy" the text but not how to paste it in the active note application. So not sure if it is the right solution.

What would be the "good practice" solution for this use case ?
Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's possible without being the default keyboard or acquiring accessibility permission. My rationale for it being impossible, is that you can create a malicious app that keeps adding random string to EditTexts everywhere telling user to pay you or messing everything up or whatever. But you must be able to do it if your app has a running Accessibility Service, but it's a weird permission :D